# Error when creating a view with a CTE

Tags: sql, view, common-table-expression

Think I am being stupid but am getting the error:

> Msg 195, Level 15, State 1, Procedure
>   VW_THIRDPARTY_SLA_REPORT_MONTHLY_GP_NONAGGREGATE, Line 8 'partitioned'
>   is not a recognized option.

when trying to execute the following create view statement

```
CREATE VIEW [dbo].[VW_THIRDPARTY_SLA_REPORT_MONTHLY_GP_NONAGGREGATE] 
With partitioned
AS 
(Select 
B.MSH7_DateTimeOfMessage,
B.PID2x1_PatientIDExternal,
B.PID3x1_PatientIDInternal,
B.PID5x1_PatientName_FamilyName,
B.PV3x2_AssignedPatientLocation_Room,
A.OBR4x2_UniversalServiceID_Text,
A.OBX3x2_ObservationIdentifier_Text,
A.OBR24_DiagnosticServiceSectionID,
A.OBR6_RequestDateTime,
C.TestName,
C.PriceBaseline,
D.Contract,
Row_NUMBER()

OVER(Partition By [ORC3_FillerOrderNumber], [OBX3x2_ObservationIdentifier_Text] order by [ORC9_DateTimeOfTransaction]) as seq
From [NWLHPathApp_DataWarehouse].[dbo].[PathologyHL7_Detail] A
LEFT OUTER JOIN [NWLHPathApp_DataWarehouse].[dbo].[PathologyHL7_Header] B ON A.[DETAIL_ID] = B.[HEADER_ID]
LEFT OUTER JOIN [NWLHPathApp_DataWarehouse].[dbo].[PathologyHL7_View_TFCData] C ON A.[OBR24_DiagnosticServiceSectionID] + A.[OBX3x1_ObservationIdentifier_Identifier] = C.[KEY]
LEFT OUTER JOIN [NWLHPathApp_DataWarehouse].[dbo].[PathologyHL7_LocationDetail] D ON B.[PV3x1_AssignedPatientLocation_PointOfCare] = D.[PracticeCode] 

)
Select *
from partitioned  
where seq =1
```

This is a query that is working nicely in a stored procedure so I am happy with the query just can't create it as a view.

Any help would be much appreciated

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You are missing the first `AS` after the [`CREATE VIEW`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187956.aspx):

```
CREATE VIEW [dbo].[VW_THIRDPARTY_SLA_REPORT_MONTHLY_GP_NONAGGREGATE] 
AS --- this is missing
  With partitioned
  AS 
  (
   Select 
      B.MSH7_DateTimeOfMessage,
      B.PID2x1_PatientIDExternal,
      B.PID3x1_PatientIDInternal,
      B.PID5x1_PatientName_FamilyName,
      B.PV3x2_AssignedPatientLocation_Room,
      A.OBR4x2_UniversalServiceID_Text,
      A.OBX3x2_ObservationIdentifier_Text,
      A.OBR24_DiagnosticServiceSectionID,
      A.OBR6_RequestDateTime,
      C.TestName,
      C.PriceBaseline,
      D.Contract,
      Row_NUMBER() OVER(Partition By [ORC3_FillerOrderNumber], [OBX3x2_ObservationIdentifier_Text] order by [ORC9_DateTimeOfTransaction]) as seq
   From [NWLHPathApp_DataWarehouse].[dbo].[PathologyHL7_Detail] A
   LEFT OUTER JOIN [NWLHPathApp_DataWarehouse].[dbo].[PathologyHL7_Header] B ON A.[DETAIL_ID] = B.[HEADER_ID]
   LEFT OUTER JOIN [NWLHPathApp_DataWarehouse].[dbo].[PathologyHL7_View_TFCData] C ON A.[OBR24_DiagnosticServiceSectionID] + A.[OBX3x1_ObservationIdentifier_Identifier] = C.[KEY]
   LEFT OUTER JOIN [NWLHPathApp_DataWarehouse].[dbo].[PathologyHL7_LocationDetail] D ON B.[PV3x1_AssignedPatientLocation_PointOfCare] = D.[PracticeCode] 

   )
   Select *
   from partitioned  
   where seq =1
```

Answer (score 6):

You need `AS` after `CREATE VIEW`:

```
CREATE VIEW [dbo].[VW_THIRDPARTY_SLA_REPORT_MONTHLY_GP_NONAGGREGATE] 
AS
With partitioned ...
```

Answer (score 2):

It might be helpful to point out that you cannot seemingly add view column titles at the same time as using CTE. (this wasted a few minutes of my time)

```
create or replace force editionable view "MYVIEW"
  --("Field1", "Field2")
as 
with results as (
    select cal.field1,cal.field2  from mytable cal
) 
select field1,field2 from results
;
```

if you uncomment the ("Field1", "Field2") column declaration above, this fails.